# How to change the artist name

Tags: app-store-connect

I am signed like company. My app was rejected because my seller name and artist name does not reflect the name of app. How can I change it? I sent them documents that I have right to use this trade mark in my country- but they did nothing.... I am so sad. I have no time to wait. Can you advece me something?

Comment: If the response by Apple is as the text I've read here (http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/106504-medical-app-rejected.html) then it looks like you did not choose the right artist name when you submitted your app for the first time (the artist name should have been your artist name -for info on this: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/49709-company-name-artist-name-displayed-on-the-app-store.html -). I would try contacting Apple directly and ask them to change the Artist name for you, since you cannot do that once you've submitted your first app.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Exactly))) what should I do? Change my artist name???How can I do it if it help me to be published?

Comment: Theoretically, there is no way. So what I would do is asking Apple to change it. I would go to https://developer.apple.com/contact/ then click on iTunes Connect Inquiries-->select iTunes Connect Error or General Help --> input all the data and ask them for a change in the name. Good luck!

Comment: thank you, hope I will solve my problem))

Comment: Can you tell me, if they change my artist name, will they notify me about this update? Or shoud I reupload my bynary again?